# TypeError: channel.isTextBased is not a function - Discord.js v14.7.1

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, node-modules

I have been running my bot on Discord.js ( Version 14.7.1 ) for a long time now without any issues, but today it started throwing a TypeError exception. I have tried updating my discord bot version but still doesn't work. It's most likely due to an updated release from Discord.js, but I can't seem to find the exact solution.

The exact error is:

```
/{path-to-project}/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:50
    if (channel && !channel.isTextBased()) return;
                            ^

TypeError: channel.isTextBased is not a function
```

Comment: Seems 14.8.0 makes it work. Are you sure you updated it? https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/9295

Comment: Yes, I updated my version to 14.8.0 but sadly it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating my discord js to 14.8.0...

just change your discord.js version in package.json to:

```
"discord.js": "^14.8.0"
```